# How can I do begin transaction in pymysql ? (mysql)

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I want to use run below mysql script using with pymysql.

```
START TRANSACTION;
BEGIN;
insert into ~~~ 
COMMIT;
```

my python source code is

```
connection = pymysql.connect(~~~~~~~)
     with connection.cursor() as cursor :
         connection.begin()
         cursor.execute(~~.sql)
         connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

My question is "connection.begin()" is the same thing "START TRANSACTION; BEGIN;" ? I want to use "START TRANSACTION; BEGIN;"

Answer (score 7):

According to the [PyMySQL docs/example](http://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/examples.html) (singular...this doesn't seem like a very well-supported package), by default auto-commit is off, so you do need to run `connection.commit()` to actually finish the transaction.

Their example:

```
import pymysql.cursors

connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                             user='user',
                             password='passwd',
                             db='db',
                             charset='utf8mb4',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `password`) VALUES (%s, %s)"
        cursor.execute(sql, ('webmaster@python.org', 'very-secret'))

    # connection is not autocommit by default. So you must commit to save changes.
    connection.commit()

finally:
    connection.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. I already used connection.commit. But sometimes, database is occured 'Lock wait timeout exceeded'. So I want to set transaction begin.

Comment: How does this work with MyISAM tables which don't have transactions to begin with? And what if we wanted to use a different transaction mode?

Answer (score 0):

pymysql.connections.Connection.begin

see [manual](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/connections.html) for more info